# Elements are floating left

Tags: html, css-float

This is the site I'm working on.
Some of the elements on the page are floating left from an iPhone.

The header and subheader are acting so.

Thanks

Comment: No offence intended - but your source code is all over the place. You are _not_ allowed to place link tags (for stylesheets and what not) in the body, which could be causing the issue. (This is for versions of HTML that are not 5).

Comment: Thanks a lot David. Could you please explain little deeper? I'm not that much expert in coding though. Where those link tags should be? It's an wordpress site. So the js and css link tags are placed on the body by default by the theme creator. Hope to hear back form you.

Comment: Oo I got it. The link tags should be on the head section right? Thanks. By the way, the site is running on Thesis theme.

Comment: They should indeed be placed in the head section. I've no idea if this will fix the issue, but it may be the cause and will probably help you later down the line. Unfortunately I've only dabbled with WordPress so can't offer much help there (and I also don't own an iPhone to check it on!). Let me know how you get on and I'll see if there is anything I can figure out that may be causing it.

Comment: Thank You David for your help. I'll come up to you if I need any help on my way fixing.